# need resultset if status = N, if status = N and status =P the result not display

Tags: mysql

table: master_consmnt:

```
fra_code    mode       cnum     cost    edate      status
ET7867FRA   SURFACE     19001   10.000  2014-01-17  P
ET7867FRA   SURFACE     19005   5.000   2014-01-17  P
ET7867FRA   SURFACE     19005   10.000  2014-01-17  P
FRANE3981   SURFACE     19005   0.000   2014-01-17  P
FRARE5664   SURFACE     19005   18.000  2014-01-17  N
FRARE5664   SURFACE     19001   14.000  2014-01-17  N
FRARE5664   SURFACE     180001  38.000  2014-01-17  N
```

I want the below result , please have a close look at master_consmnt table, the table having multiple cnum with status=P or N. We want a result set which has cnum if not status="P" and status="N".

```
fra_code    mode      cnum  cost    edate           status
FRARE5664   SURFACE 180001  38.000  2014-01-17  N
```

Comment: What is the current query? What problems are you having getting this to work?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `master_consmnt` WHERE not(`status`="N" or `status`="P")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `not exists`:

```
select mc.*
from master_consmnt mc
where mc.status = 'N' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from master_consmnt mc2
                  where mc2.cnum = mc.cnum and status = 'P'
                 );
```

Comment: this is showing only status=N value not displaying conditional statement if status=N and status=P, please look i want resultset if cnum not equal to status=P

Comment: if in not exists we replace fra_code with cnum and mc.fra_code with mc.cnum then the neded result is displaying..thanks